# Creating a searchable directory on Hivebrite that accesses data stored in a google sheet

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a directory on a Hivebrite page that users can utilize to search other users by name, state, zip code, etc. The data needing to be accessed for this is stored in a Google sheet. I have made the sheet "public" and set up the google sheet API, but it will not generate any results or show the data table when I try to preview the page. Any tips would be greatly appreciated :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Online Directory</title>
    <style>
        /* Your CSS styles here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search...">
        <ul id="directoryList"></ul>
        <div id="noResultsMessage">No results found.</div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#searchInput').on('input', searchDirectory);

            // Google Sheets API key
            var apiKey = 'AIzaSyBldgrtW7K5Hvm88n8szuXbgx4WlkPGy5U';

            // Google Sheets Spreadsheet ID
            var spreadsheetId = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O-3zjSGdQ9ZVG4KomiEYSIejmjkgi9slPkpODpFkJKQ/edit#gid=411563656';

            // Function to fetch and display data from the Google Sheets API
            function fetchDataFromSheet() {
                var apiUrl = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + spreadsheetId + '/values/Sheet1?key=' + apiKey;

                fetch(apiUrl)
                    .then(response => {
                        if (!response.ok) {
                            throw new Error('Failed to fetch data from Google Sheets. Status: ' + response.status);
                        }
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log('Fetched data:', data);
                        displayData(data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
                        // You can add further error handling or logging here
                    });
            }

            // Function to display data on the web page
            function displayData(data) {
                console.log('Displaying data...');

                var directoryList = $('#directoryList');
                var noResultsMessage = $('#noResultsMessage');
                directoryList.empty();
                noResultsMessage.hide();

                // Process the data and append it to the list
                var values = data.values || [];
                values.forEach(function (row) {
                    var listItem = $('<li class="directory-item"></li>');
                    listItem.html(
                        'ID: ' + (row[0] || '') +
                        ' | Last Name: ' + (row[1] || '') +
                        ' | First Name: ' + (row[2] || '') +
                        ' | Email: ' + (row[3] || '') +
                        ' | Website: ' + (row[4] || '') +
                        ' | Address: ' + (row[5] || '') +
                        ' | ZIP/Postal code: ' + (row[6] || '') +
                        ' | City: ' + (row[7] || '') +
                        ' | State/Region/Province: ' + (row[8] || '') +
                        ' | Country: ' + (row[9] || '') +
                        ' | Country code: ' + (row[10] || '')
                    );
                    directoryList.append(listItem);
                });

                // Trigger search after displaying data
                searchDirectory();
            }

            // Function to show all items when the page loads
            function showAllItems() {
                var directoryList = $('#directoryList');
                directoryList.find('.directory-item').show();
            }

            // Function to handle the initial data fetch
            fetchDataFromSheet();

            // Show all items when the page loads
            showAllItems();

            // Function to handle search functionality
            function searchDirectory() {
                console.log('Searching directory...');

                var filter = $('#searchInput').val().toUpperCase(); // Convert the search term to uppercase
                var directoryList = $('#directoryList');
                var noResultsMessage = $('#noResultsMessage');
                var resultsFound = false;

                directoryList.find('.directory-item').each(function () {
                    var txtValue = $(this).text().toUpperCase(); // Convert the text content to uppercase
                    if (filter === '' || txtValue.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        $(this).show();
                        resultsFound = true;
                    } else {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                });

                if (!resultsFound) {
                    noResultsMessage.show();
                } else {
                    noResultsMessage.hide();
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that in your script, `spreadsheetId` is the Spreadsheet URL. Is this related to your current issue?